# Grid of image with automatic padding

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating an image grid where there is a slider that changes the size of the images itself.

see example:
http://jsfiddle.net/9Tce5/1/

My problem is when the width of the contender, represented in red, is not large enough to fill the row without leaving an empty area (like in the sample).

What I would like to achieve is to fit the li element, represented in green so that it would fit the whole row until the slider is moved and the images are getting larger or smaller. In short, I would like the whole raw to be filled with green.

This is my css:

```
ul {
    width:410px;
    background-color:red;
    height:100%;
    display:table;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin:5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color:green;
}
.image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 75px;
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I can solve this with javascript like so, but isn't there a cooler/CSS way?

```
var ul_width = $('ul').width();
var li_width = $('li').first().outerWidth()+2;
var modulo = Math.floor(ul_width/li_width)

var padding = (ul_width-(li_width*modulo))/modulo/2
$('li').css('padding',padding);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the `li`s to 33.3333% and remove the `margin`.

Remove `display:table;` from the `ul`.

Use `border-box` to avoid annoying math with the padding.

```
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Tce5/4/

Comment: _FF still needs vendor-prefix for box-sizing_ ;)

Comment: autoprefixer has been spoiling me.

Comment: same with me , it's usefull :)

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that when the image size is changed by the slider, I can no longer have the li set to 33%. In other words, the number of images in each row is changed by their size.

Comment: This is a very different thing.

Comment: I actually found some old code that might be able to help you with this: http://jsbin.com/IbeGIlO/9 You can just ignore all the JS and look at the CSS.

Comment: Sadly, there's no good CSS way to do this without a shit load of media queries.

Comment: If you're using Sass I did this a bit ago: https://gist.github.com/crswll/9259685

Answer (score 0):

You set margins and paddings, but you could set width too and margin:auto to childs element:
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9Tce5/3/)

```
ul {
    width:410px;
    background-color:red;
    height:100%;
    display:table;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin:5px 0.8%;
    padding: 4% 0.8%;
    background-color:green;
    width:30%;
}
.image, .title {
    width: 100px;
    margin:auto;
    display: block;
}
.image {
    height: 75px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

---

to totally hide red `background`: reset `margin`s and li's `width`. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9Tce5/5/)**

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin:0;
    padding: 4% 1%;
    background-color:green;
    width:31.3%;
}
```